# Delete user in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am executing this code to create user in my database.

```
CREATE LOGIN john WITH PASSWORD = 'john123';
GO

USE mytestdb;
GO
CREATE USER [john] FOR LOGIN [john]
GO
ALTER USER [john] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [john]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [john]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [john]
GO
```

But I want to delete this my created user.

I tried to issue this command

```
USE myDB;
DROP USER john;
GO
```

but it throws this error.

> The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped.

Comment: [***READ THE DOCS!***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189438.aspx) - it's all out there - you just need to **do some searching** yourself !

Comment: I tried this DROP USER [ IF EXISTS ] john , but it has syntax error

Comment: SQL Server 2014 (that you're using) doesn't support the `IF EXISTS` notion yet - just use `DROP USER john;` ....

Comment: okay I remove the if exists now. but it gives me error I updated my post

Comment: #1 in Google search for "SQL Server" (and your error message above): [How to fix error 15138: ....](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/12/26/sql-server-fix-error-15138-the-database-principal-owns-a-schema-in-the-database-and-cannot-be-dropped/)

Comment: We really need a "lmgtfy" flag :D

Answer (score 1):

You can see schemas owners there:

```
SELECT s.name AS [schema_name], dp1.name AS [owner_name]
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp1 ON dp1.principal_id = s.principal_id
```

Then change owner:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[xxxx] TO [dbo]
```

"xxxx" - name of schema which owner is 'john' now

Comment: what is apps ?is that my database name ?